# Percentage with top 10 values in Python

Tags: pandas, data-analysis, exploratory-data-analysis

Need some help in getting top 10 values and percentages in Python. The Code I've already tried is given below:-

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df=pd.read_csv('train_feature_store.csv')
df.info
df.head
df.columns

plt.figure(figsize=(20,6))
sns.countplot(x='Store', data=df)
plt.show()

Size = df[['Size','Store']].groupby(['Store'], as_index=False).sum()
Size.sort_values(by=['Size'],ascending=False).head(10)
```

Now, what the above last two lines of the code is giving me is this:-

[Result_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9eBV.png)

However, What I'm expecting is this:-

[Expectation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUQha.png)

Unfortunately, I'm not able to write the code for the percentage values. Can anyone help me with that please..!! Thanks..! [:)]

Please also find the source data file on which I'm running the code.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1j77Xvl1mzUAPNZ53b89LzODSu1ZsbvEJ/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

After doing this:

```
Size = df[['Size','Store']].groupby(['Store'], as_index=False).sum()
```

You can do the following:

```
df1 = Size.sort_values(by=['Size'],ascending=False).head(10).reset_index(drop=True)
df1['Percentage'] = (df1['Size'] / df1['Size'].sum()) * 100
df1.loc[10,:] = ['Grand Total', df1.Size.sum(), 100]
```

output:

```
>>> df1
          Store          Size  Percentage
0         AANUR  2.297026e+09   10.934090
1         AADRA  2.113595e+09   10.060939
2        ABOHAR  2.083650e+09    9.918396
3      ABLIMARA  2.082268e+09    9.911819
4       AAMTALA  2.082045e+09    9.910755
5   ABHIKANAGAR  2.080992e+09    9.905743
6      ABERDEEN  2.073279e+09    9.869026
7     AADILABAD  2.066768e+09    9.838037
8     ACHALGANJ  2.064784e+09    9.828592
9       AALIPUR  2.063526e+09    9.822603
10  Grand Total  2.100793e+10  100.000000
```

Comment: Thanks @Tobias for your answer. However, I am not getting any output. Also, in your code I'm Not able to find the Store feature. Could you please help.

Comment: I've added more info at the beginning. `df1` will be your output

Comment: WOW..!! Nice..!! Thanks..!! need another help though.. Any way to get the percentage values to be rounded off and not getting truncated values in size also..?

Comment: `df1.Percentage = df1.Percentage.round(2)`